# How do I filter multiple tables in a dataset?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a strongly typed dataset that has about a dozen tables, all linked via relationships. Just as an example, some of the major tables are invoice, invoice_lines, invoice_journal, invoice_log, invoice_metadata; all linked as you might expect by invoice_id. There are also some third level tables hanging off the children linked by their respective parent row ids.

I wish to filter my entire dataset based on the top level invoice, for the purpose of the example I'll keep it simple where invoice_id == 2265 (just an example), or parent_invoice == null;

I would expect after applying the filter to see only rows in each table that correspond to the top level table.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984340%28v=vs.71%29.aspx